# is it possible to find or define resources from/in a library?

Tags: c#, mvvm, dialog, mef

I have an *WPF* Application [here](http://github.com/c3rebro/rfidgear) which is in the *MVVM* Pattern using *MVVMLight* as Framework and a *MEF* Plugin with a UserControl named *VCNEditor*.

The Main Application uses an *Attached Behaviour* named DialogViewModel of Type DialogBehavior to display Dialogboxes. The DialogBehavior takes care of binding the view to its pre-created `DialogViewModel : IDialogViewModel` (viewmodel first) by using:

```
var resource = Application.Current.TryFindResource(viewModel.GetType());
```

The Plugin is a Library with a UserControl. The UserControl is Lazy loaded dynamically from an "Extensions" directory and only visible if present.

That works so far. The Problem i currently facing is: I tried to Display Dialogboxes within my Plugin in the same way i do within the Main Application.

Meaning: I defined a Property Named "Dialogs" of Type

```
ObservableCollection<IDialogViewModel>
```

in my `UserControlViewModel : IDialogViewModel` and DataBind that Property to my *Attached Behavior*.

When i now Add a new DialogViewModel to that collection

`Application.Current.TryFindResource(viewModel.GetType())`

is not able to find any resource because Application.Current is returning the Main Application and the library doesnt have any resource dictionary like in app.xaml in the main application.

I cannot add resources for the dialogs of the plugin to the Main Application because this will break my loosely coupled plugin architecture.

I am just a casual-developer and it would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction.
The current workaround is, that i create the view "by hand" in every viewmodels construcor. But i think that this doenst look very well.

Thank you for your Support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you can easily add your plugin styles and resources to the `Application.Current.Resources` in code.

One way to solve this will be to create a merged Dictionary architecture for your plugins. On your *MEF* plugin *Interface* implement a `HasResource` `bool` *Property*, and `ResourceDictionary/ResourceDictionaries` *Property*.

When you plugin loads, simply check for those properties and if has resources just add them to the host application via

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(myResourceDictionary);
```

**Additional Resources**

[Application.Resources Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.resources%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Gets or sets a collection of application-scope resources, such as
>   styles and brushes.

[ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets a collection of the ResourceDictionary dictionaries that
>   constitute the various resource dictionaries in the merged
>   dictionaries.

[ResourceDictionary Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Provides a hash table / dictionary implementation that contains WPF
>   resources used by components and other elements of a WPF application.

Comment: ok, that was great so far. thank you. I've successfully imported the main apps ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries into my plugins mainvm. But: How to Add a resource that binds a specific type of a viewmodel to its view? In xaml i just did:

`<dialogsview:CustomDialogBox x:Key="{x:Type dialogsvm:CustomDialogViewModel}" x:Shared="False" />`

But i need to do this in the code now.

Comment: got it like:


`ResourceDictionary vcnEditorRD = new ResourceDictionary();
    vcnEditorRD.Add(typeof(ScheduleConfigurationDialogViewModel), typeof(ScheduleConfigurationDialogView));
    
    ResourceDictionaries.MergedDictionaries.Add(vcnEditorRD);`